# "Diophantine" equation $x^r+y^r = z^r$ for more arbitrary choices of $r$.

Tags: number-theory

Today I was interested in the following. I assume that every mathematician walking on this earth knows, that the set of positive integer exponents $n$, for which there exist a solution in positive integers $x, y, z$, to the equation $$x^n+y^n = z^n$$is $\{1, 2\}$. This is known as Fermat's Last Theorem (FLT for short), a long-lasting problem in mathematics, which was solved by Andrew Wiles.

Why not go a step further, and consider the set $S$ of complex exponents $r$, for which there exist positive integers $x, y, z$, such that $$x^r+y^r = z^r? $$

By $x^r$ where $r\in\mathbb{C}, x\in\mathbb{Z_+}$, I mean that $x^r = \exp(r\ln(x))$.

The first property of this set, equivalent to FLT, is that $S\cap\mathbb{Z} = \{-2, -1, 1, 2\}$. Another obvious property, is that this set is symmetric with respect to the point $(0, 0)$, that is, if $r\in S$, then $-r\in S$. This can be written in short as $S = -S$.

If $r$ is a rational number of the form $\frac{n}{m}$, where $\gcd(n, m) = 1$, $n>2$, a result of Bennett, Glass, and Székely from 2004 gives that the equation
$$x^{n/m}+y^{n/m} = z^{n/m} $$ has no solutions in positive integers $x, y, z$. This means, that $$S\cap\mathbb{Q}_+ \subseteq \{\frac{2}{n} : n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}.$$

Is this set known in literature? What are some of the known properties of this set?

Comment: At least $S\cap\Bbb{R}$ is dense in $\Bbb{R}$: Let $a$ and $b$ be distinct integers and set
$$r:=\frac{\ln2}{\ln b-\ln a},$$
so that for $(x,y,z)=(a,a,b)$ we have
$$x^r+y^r=z^r.$$
The result you quote shows that $S\cap\Bbb{R}$ contains no nonempty open subsets of $\Bbb{R}$. Similar arguments are likely to show that $S$ is dense in $\Bbb{C}$, and contains no nonempty open subsets of $\Bbb{C}$. By my standards that makes $S$ an awful set.